# Game Data Mining & Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, games

I would like to learn how can I learn to set up a script that will learn to play a game, I'm thinking [agar.io](http://agar.io/) specifically. I believe to do this I basically must make the program mine the game for data, play the game, learn about the data that it has found, and then apply it to it's playing style. Now, how do I do that.

[agar.io](http://agar.io/) is a (I believe html) game where you are what I will call a "blob." Players generally move their blob around the game space with the main goal of collecting mass. You can collect mass from littered other smaller blobs (inanimate, ~2 mass, no adverse effect), viruses (100 mass but they split your blob into smaller blobs), and other players. As your mass rises you become slower. However, you can not eat anything larger than yourself (and I believe you need to be larger by ~25%). Thus it is hard to chase down another player, you have two controls however which make this pvp chase possible, you can either split your cell, causing you to basically shoot half of yourself at them. Which of course requires you to be significantly larger than the other blob. You also have to option to eject mass at the other player, causing them to become slower and larger. Thus if they make mistakes when you do not you will be more likely to catch them and be able to eat them. This also has adverse consequences though, since you will be following them, they will be collecting any mass in the way and thus becoming larger while you're shrinking given the time shrink effect on mass. Thus, you must be able to bet they will make a mistake quickly, or they will be able to eat you instead. This game sounds really complex to me now that I describe it. There's a reason I provided [the link](http://agar.io/) to [the website](http://agar.io/) of [the game](http://agar.io/).

I'm a math major and want an actual applied understanding of machine learning. I picked this game specifically because it has a very leveled progression of complexity.

Also, I believe that when people set these up normally it is in a stand alone environment so the computer can play it's self multiple times. I feel like an algorithm for this game would be useless in a stand alone setting. (Although it may be interesting to build it that way and see how much opponents playing non-optimally messes it up.)

Since typing this post originally I have become very interested in not specifically the results of such a project, being able to play this game, but actually the differences in the way humans would choose to play the game verses the way that AI would choose to play the game given independent choices to maximize their own mass without regard to other players. Then equally interestingly, how these differences would interact in a human vs bot game.

Comment: please describe the game

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish big projects, you need to split them up into many small projects.

The first project is reading in game data. This depends heavily on how the game itself is set up; if it's rendered in a browser you'll be learning how to parse HTML, if it's rendered as an image you'll be learning how to interpret images, or how to extract the game state from the raw network traffic.

The second project is making moves. Again, this is heavily dependent on the game itself; this might require making POST requests, or taking control of the keyboard or mouse, or so on.

The third project is planning moves. Here we need some sort of abstract model of the game states, but we can assume the state of the game is already in a convenient format and we can easily execute whatever moves we settle on (output in whatever format we like). What form this takes depends on the size of the game tree; if it's Tic Tac Toe, for example, we can exhaustively enumerate all possible branches in our optimization algorithm, but if it's Chess, we need to be cleverer or our program will take an unacceptably long time to run.

The fourth project is learning the parameters for a planner. Here we might have a thousand recorded games, and from those we want to know what to expect from opponents (which we can plug into our planner to make better decisions).

Only the fourth is obviously a 'data mining' project, and unfortunately these all require fairly different skillsets or libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It won't let me add a comment until 50 reputation, but here is some advice.
Automating game play is usually split into two categories - by looking at the data that is coming in before it is turned into a picture on your screen, or by looking at the data AFTER it is turned into a picture (a visual approach, the same way a human would play the game)
I played one round of the game and from that limited experience I would go with the visual approach. The game displays as a PNG image anyways so that could make things easier. Capture the screen and shrink it down to keep the data minimal. Use this as input into a network that has two outputs (x and y) that correspond to where the mouse should move to with a given input.

To train it, you could have it watch you play. Have it calculate where it thinks the mouse should go for every update, and compare that to where you actually moved your mouse. Find gradients that make the output closer to what you did, update weights accordingly, and repeat.
This is just a basic idea though. No guarantee it will work.